# Some of my conditions are being overlooked

Tags: javascript

This small app is to tell how fast a driver was going, when I test this code it only alerts the first condition, no matter what my entry is and this is a serious bug, this is the code I appreciate all help thanks in advance to all

```
    alert(
        "Welcome this program tells you how fast you were driving your 
         vehicle, in km/h");

var top_speed = parseInt(prompt("How many km/h you was at?"));

if (top_speed >= 60) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a normal speed");

} else if (top_speed >= 80) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a moderate 
    speed");

} else if (top_speed >= 120) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h that is a very high 
    speed");

} else {
    alert("You need to go faster " + top_speed + "km/h is too slow ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The statements are evaluated from top to bottom. As 80 and 120 are both also `>= 60`, the first condition will always match for values of 60 and above.

Simply switch the order:

```
if (top_speed >= 120) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h that is a very high 
    speed");

} else if (top_speed >= 80) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a moderate 
    speed");

} else if (top_speed >= 60) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a normal speed");

} else {
    alert("You need to go faster " + top_speed + "km/h is too slow ");
}
```

An alternative would be to be more specific in your conditions, i.e. also include an upper bound:

```
if (top_speed >= 60 && top_speed < 80) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a normal speed");

} else if (top_speed >= 80 && top_speed < 120) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a moderate 
    speed");

} else if (top_speed >= 120) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h that is a very high 
    speed");

} else {
    alert("You need to go faster " + top_speed + "km/h is too slow ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the first condition `top_speed >= 60` is `true` whenever the other two conditions `top_speed >= 80` and `top_speed >= 120` are true.Whenever any of conditions will be `true` it will not check others which are below that. You should change the order.

```js
var top_speed = parseInt(prompt("How many km/h you was at?"));

if (top_speed >= 120) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h that is a very high speed");

}
else if (top_speed >= 80) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a moderate speed");
}  
else if (top_speed >= 60) {
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a normal speed");

} 
 else {
    alert("You need to go faster " + top_speed + "km/h is too slow ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse your check conditions:

Just imagine, when you input `140`, that value is greater than `60` so the code will enter on the first `if` condition, and none of the other conditions will be inspected.

```js
alert("Welcome this program tells you how fast you were driving your vehicle, in km/h");

var top_speed = parseInt(prompt("How many km/h you was at?"));

if (top_speed >= 120)
{
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a very high speed");
}
else if (top_speed >= 80)
{
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h thats a moderate speed");
}
else if (top_speed >= 60)
{
    alert("You were driving at " + top_speed + "km/h that is a normal speed");
}
else
{
    alert("You need to go faster " + top_speed + "km/h is too slow ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good answers already here (they are the true answer), I think I should also mention this in case someone else has a similar problem.

Else if is only executed if the first condition is false. That is to say, a string of else ifs will ONLY execute the FIRST true condition. If none exists, only then will it execute the else or, if none exists, do nothing.